# Error while installing Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have done accordingly as shown in this below 2 tutorial

> http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/zend/installing-zend-framework
>   http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/zend/testing-your-zend-framework-installation

But on the installation checker, I get the following error .

```
    Zend Framework Installation Errors  Tested
0   Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php
```

The following are the paths I tried to include in php.ini

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php/home/content/54/10750054/html/zf/library"
```

And

```
include_path = "/home/content/54/10750054/html/zf/library"
```

I get the same error either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, there is no file `Zend/Loader.php` in ZF2. The "testing your Zend Framework installation" article appears to have been written for ZF1 (and not the most recent version of it).

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is the best way to install ZF2, and you should be doing this on your own machine (or development machine) rather than straight on to your production hosting. I'd suggest you see how you get on with the instructions in the main ZF2 docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/overview.html

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Ignored that installation checker.

Unfortunately I can't do that on my local computer, I'm doing this for a client of mine.

I believe I did everything right now, but how will I know I installed it correctly this time? How do I check?

Comment: try `var_dump(file_exists('Zend/Version/Version.php'));`. But this is only one part of the puzzle, you'll need to setup autoloading in order to be able to use the ZF classes.